# How to display a Navigation Property of a table inside a Data control like a FormView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

Ok I have a many to many relationship like this:

```
Walk = {WalkID, title, ...., (Navigation Properties) Features}
Feature = {FeatureID, featureName, description, (Navigation Properties) DogWalks}
```

I do of course have a junction table, but EF assumes this thus it is not shown in my edmx diagram:

```
WalkFeatures = {WalkID, FeatureID} //junction, both FK
```

So using LINQ with EF, I am now trying to grab the features for the `Walk` at `WalkID=xx`.

This is my `formview`:

```
<asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" ItemType="Walks.DAL.Walk" SelectMethod="FormView1_GetItem">
    <ItemTemplate>
      <h1><%# Item.Title %></h1>
      ...
    </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:FormView
 <asp:Label ID="lbFeatures" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

And selectMethod:

```
public Walks.DAL.Walk FormView1_GetItem([QueryString("WalkID")] int? WalkID)
{
  using (WalkContext db = new WalkContext())
  {
   var walk = (from n in db.Walks.Include("Features")
               where n.WalkID == WalkID
               select n).SingleOrDefault();

    foreach(var f in walk.Features){
        lbFeatures.Text += f.FeatureName + "<br/>";

    }
   return walk;
  }          
}
```

The code runs fine, but is there a way that I can display the `Walk.Features` directly inside the `<ItemTemplate>` of the `formview` rather than using a label and a loop? Can the attribute be directly binded like the other properties in the `.aspx` page?

Comment: But your label control `lbFeatures`is not inside the `FormView`, how you expect the datasource to work outside from the control?

Comment: @RahulSingh yes that is true and as mentioned the code does run fine in the current setup. But there must be a way to display everything from within the `<ItemTemplate>' rather than relying on the external label. Also note I can't move the label inside the template since it gives me a compile error (the current code cannot see it).

Comment: Check my answer, probably this may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also used this new feature not that extensively but just gave it a try for this particular scenario and this is what I have:-

Simply return `walk` from `FormView1_GetItem` method and don't manipulate your label control there. Now, you can use a `Repeater` control to display the `lbFeatures` control (since it is going to repeat dynamically) like this:-

```
<ItemTemplate>
   <h1><%# Item.Title %></h1>
   <asp:Repeater ID="lbFeatures" runat="server" DataSource='<%# Item.Features%>'>
      <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Label ID="lblTest" runat="server" 
                     Text='<%# Eval("FeatureName") %>'></asp:Label>
          <br />
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:Repeater>
</ItemTemplate>
```

As you can see I am able to assign the datasouce of repater control as `Item.Features`, then use the conventional approach to bind the label. This looks clean and simple :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, this is very much the sort of thing I was after. +1, your example works flawlessly. Thanks :)

Comment: Hi I was wondering if you could help me again. Same sort of situation but this time a `one to many relationship` for my images. How can I display only a single image inside a formview from many? I've managed to correctly list the images using your method of a repeater, but if I only want 1 item out of a collection, what method should I use? Thanks in advance

Comment: @gudthing - Hey since `Features` is a collection of items you can use LINQ `First()` method like this:- `<asp:Label ID="lblFeatureName" runat="server" Text='<%# Item.Features.First().FeatureName %>'></asp:Label>`

Comment: Rahul I really cannot thank you enough! Thank you again for your time!